# Best design to handle condition based method calls

Tags: java, design-patterns

What can be best design pattern for handling condition based method calls? Conditions are based on string comparison. I know basic if-else-if or switch can solve it but still looking for other solution.

**Example:**

User inputs the strings `foo1`, `foo2` and `foo3` in sequential order. Now the program calls a method on the basis of these inputs i.e.:

```
if (input.equals("foo1"))
   fun1();
else if(input.equals("foo2"))
   fun2();
```

and so on.

Also, the functionality of `fun1()` and `fun2()` are entirely independent of each other.

Comment: Can you provide more details? `Conditions are based on string comparison`? Please give an example

Comment: The question is too broad. Depending on what exactly is needed you may consider to use a finite state machine or other techniques.

Comment: Just want to clarify, why do you need to do this? is method name alone is sufficient enough? refer a method by a string is double the work to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. In your case, there isn't one. But usually you would solve this by some form of polymorphism or Template Method pattern. But your data model doesn't seem to have been designed in such a way, so you're pretty much screwed, and you'll have to make an ugly nested IF structure. Alternatively you can refactor it slightly and use a Template Method Pattern. In this scenario you could use a Factory method pattern to create different templates based on the String, each of these templates would thn have a different `TemplateMethod()` which would be invoked. This allows you to treat all object equally, yet have one part (the template method) act independently.

For a more in-depth explanation, see: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Template_method_pattern

**Edit**: Added example, of less shitty Factory method.

TemplateFactory.java

```
public class TemplateFactory {
    private Map<String, Class> map;

    public TemplateFactory() {
        this.map = new TreeMap<>();
        map.put("Template 1", Template1.class);
        map.put("Template 2", Template2.class);
    }

    public BaseTemplate createBaseTemplate(String comparison)
    {
        if (!map.containsKey(comparison))
        {
            return null;
        }
        try {
            return (BaseTemplate) map.get(comparison).getConstructor().newInstance();
        } catch (InstantiationException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvocationTargetException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchMethodException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        TemplateFactory tf = new TemplateFactory();
        BaseTemplate t1 = tf.createBaseTemplate("Template 1");
        BaseTemplate t2 = tf.createBaseTemplate("Template 2");
        System.out.println(t1.templateMethod(""));
        System.out.println(t2.templateMethod(""));
    }
}
```

BaseTemplate.java

```
public abstract class BaseTemplate {
    public String doSomething()
    {
        // whatever
        return "Hello";
    }

    public int anotherRealMethod(String data)
    {
        //also whatever
        return 0;
    }

    public abstract String templateMethod(String data);
}
```

Template1.java

```
public class Template1 extends BaseTemplate {
    @Override
    public String templateMethod(String data) {
        return "Template 1";
    }
}
```

Template 2.java

```
public class Template1 extends BaseTemplate {
    @Override
    public String templateMethod(String data) {
        return "Template 2";
    }
}
```

Comment: Even factory pattern utilizes ugly if-else-if structure (just a naive example http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/factory_pattern.htm shape factory Class). Now imagine hundreds of different shapes (circle,square,pentagon...so on) so this shapefactory class will look horrible. I am just looking for any nicer way.

Comment: Not necessarily. That's a shitty example. A better example would be to keep a `Map<String, Class>´ in your factory and then lookup the class you need, and either get it as a dependency from your IoC container, or simply create a new instance.

Comment: @avenger I have updated my answer to include an example which elaborates on my answer. Ideally you should use an IoC container (like  the Spring BeanFactory or the Guice Injector) to create and handle your object lifecycle, rather than using reflection. But setting that up is a bit out of the scope of the question.

Comment: Also @PhamTrung is correct that you should use a Typesafe Enumerator over String values.

Answer (score 0):

In your case, I will consider a combination of `enum` and `switch case`. The reason we should not use string for this is:

- If you use a misspelled string to called your function (`getFunction("foO")` instead of `getFuntion("foo")`) , you don't have any idea how to debug it, the compiler will not tell you anything.
- And If you mistakenly used two identical String to refer to two different methods, you could not detect it also.
- You cannot iterate through all of your string , `enum` has a `values()` method for that.

So my advice is use an `enum`

```
public enum Function{
  foo1,
  foo2;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify it by using Runnables instead of a factory:

```
public class Router {
    private Map<String, Class> map;

    public Router() {
        this.map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put("foo1", new Runnable(){
            run(){
                fun1();
            }
        });
        map.put("foo2", new Runnable(){
            run(){
                fun2();
            }
        });
    }

    public void doRoot(String command) throws IllegalArgumentException {
        Runnable r = map.get(command);
        if(r == null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("invalid command: " + command);
        }
        r.run();
    }

    fun1(){}

    fun2(){}

}
```